# Networked drive in purgatory after `net use` start-up script

Tags: networking, command-line, nant, network-share

I have a BAT file that runs on startup via the group policy on an internal server. The BAT executes a nant script which then maps several external locations via `net use` command. Until now, all mappings have been to external computers that are part of a different domain via public IPs.

```
net use e: \\111.111.111.111\someshare$ /persistent:yes
net use f: \\111.111.111.222\someshare$ /persistent:yes
net use g: \\111.111.111.333\someshare$ /persistent:yes
```

This has been successful. Now, I added a new computer that is part of the *same network and domain* as the internal server. While the old mappings continue to work, the new mapping does not.

```
net use h: \\anothercomputer\d$\somefolder /persistent:yes
```

I only know that this doesn't work because subsequent scripts that depend on this drive mapping are all failing, saying that the location doesn't exist. If I try to run the same connection script manually, `net use` says

> System error 85 has occurred... The local device name is already in use.

Ok, so it mapped already somewhere, somehow. So I try to unmap it using `net use h: /d` and that fails.

> The network connection could not be found.

So I cannot map it. I cannot unmap it. Apparently it exists in some networking purgatory. What is going on here? How can I get this new location mapped and visible to my scripts?

Comment: well, mapping to a $ administrative share is not so secure. is it possible for you to define the `somefolder` as a shared folder ? then you can use something like: `net use h: \\anothercomputer\somefolder /persistent:yes` and this would probalby work.

Comment: Yes, I can set up shares. Trying it now.

Comment: Didnt appear to change anything. I am going to get SysInternals so I can run a command prompt as `Local System` So i can double check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if drive h: was mapped using a different account. When a drive is mapped from a service, it is only available from the system account, and there is also a different running it normally, or using the UAC "Run as administrator" feature. If you want to unmap it, you must do it the same way as it was mapped.

You can check if you can ping the other computer before trying to map a drive.

You can also try to connect to the other computer using an explicit username and password. And if you map it in a login script, there is no need to use the /persistent option.

```
net use \\anothercomputer /user:username password > c:\temp\netuse.log 2>&1
net use h: \\anothercomputer\d$\somefolder
```

In the example above I write the output of the first net use command to a logfile, so you can check for errormessages afterwards.

If you use the /persistent option, you should not need to remap it again, you can use

```
if exist h:\nul ...
```

to check if drive h: already exists.

Comment: I already had another means of getting the command output but when I tried this way `> c:\whatever.txt`, i was getting different output. very strange. anyway, the new log was able to help me pinpoint the exact problem (wrong user name and password) and correct my script. thanks!

Comment: The first point "mapped using a different account - e.g. system account" was key. In admin cmd prompt, I used Sysinternals `psexec -s -i cmd.exe` to become the system account, typed `net use`, verified presence of the "hidden" mapped drive, deleted it via `net use` and now a regular user account can map to the drive letter again. Old post, I know, but still relevant. Many thanks @wimh!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has documented that this is a problem prevalent in following systems:

Microsoft Windows 2000 Server

Microsoft Windows 2000 Advanced Server

Microsoft Windows 2000 Professional Edition

If your internal server is running any of these then this link below will definitely help you.
Even other wise it does not harm to check out the solution. Also Check out the windows registry changes section at the bottom of the page in the link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308337#top

Comment: there was no terminal services involved, and i am using win 2003 sp2 anyway. thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

Might be a client issue.

The following MS support article identifies a problem that has the described symptoms.

Resolution is to change a registry value in the client that is attempting to map the drive.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/253821

Answer (score 0):

A more programatic way if the system account is hogging it. No psexec needed.

In PowerShell admin prompt:

```
New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
Remove-Item "HKU:\.DEFAULT\Network\H"
```

Restart the computer (unfortunately).